# targeting all zip files starting with a certain string and ending with a certain one

Tags: wildcards, zip

I ran the following command to `zip` all files starting with `db-` and ending with `.sql`:

```
zip /var/www/html/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip /var/www/html/^db-*.sql
```

Yet I get:

> zip warning: name not matched: /var/www/html/^db-*.sql
>
> zip error: Nothing to do! (/var/www/html/db.zip)

As I used a caret to match all starting with `db-`, and than added in `*.sql` in the end to match all ending with `.sql`, I don't understand my mistake.

I tried other variations with `^` but all failed with a similar error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash parameters are not regular expressions, they are globs.  Use:

```
$ zip /var/www/html/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip /var/www/html/db-*.sql
```

From `bash`'s manual, under "Pattern Matching":

> `*`      Matches  any string, including the null string.  When the `globstar` shell option is enabled, and `*` is
>                        used in a pathname expansion context, two adjacent `*`s used as a single pattern will match all  files
>                        and  zero  or  more  directories and subdirectories.  If followed by a `/`, two adjacent `*`s will match
>                        only directories and subdirectories.

Comment: Also, filename globbing patterns are anchored by default, so `db-*.sql` would match any filename starting with `db-` and ending with `.sql`. Regular expressions are different.

Comment: You'd also want to add the `-nw` option to avoid `zip` doing its own wildcard interpretation (in addition to the shells), or quote the glob for the shell so that it's done in `zip` instead. (or use a more unixy command like `bsdtar` to  create the `zip` file to avoid this kind of msdos-like behaviour).

Comment: I think I miss why regex can be used in `sed` or `awk` or `grep` (AFAICR), but not on `zip`.

Comment: That's because `sed` and `awk` and `grep` _are_ regular expression tools, built to use them (the 're' in `grep` actually stands for 'regular expression' -- Global Regular Expression Print -- from its origins in (as I recall) an `ex` (or possibly `ed`) command).  Shells such as `bash` and tools such as `zip` are not.